# SSO between two websites in different platforms

Tags: single-sign-on

I have a requirement where I need to implement SSO between two different websites.

One of the website say www.abc.com is written using ASP.NET and is hosted on IIS 7.0. The second website say www.xyz.com is written using PHP and uses Apache web server. Both the websites uses different databases and uses different algorithms to authenticate the user.

I cannot use a third party SSO as that would mean changing the authentication for both the websites. Wanted to know if this is possible and if yes, what should be the approach?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have matching user records in each database i.e. does user id x exist in both app 1 and app 2?

Comment: no, they both are totally different websites, but they may have users who have common e-mail id's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could find an alternative approach. Basically, we were trying to address this issue by using two cookies (one each for www.abc.com and www.xyz.com created by each site), but since we were unable to find a way for reading cross-domain cookies, we were stuck up.

But then, I stumbled upon the way forums.asp.net and hotmail works. They use the live.microsoft.com to set the authentication cookie.

Now, we plan to create a third website for authenticating the user. The login forms in both the www.abc.com and www.xyz.com will call the third website to set the authentication cookie. Using this authentication cookie, we will be able to allow user to have seamless browsing across both the websites.

Also, found a very good article on this implementation.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic